# If whitespace not working properly with charAt

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, whitespace, charat

In this code I get a random string from the site codeHs, what I have to
Do is create a program to return the random string like this, if `str` was `= hello` this will be the output `-->`  `Hello` then `hEllo` then `heLlo` then `helLo` then `hellO`, Its also supposed to skip whitespaces and just go to the next variable

my current code is

```
function wave(str){
  var str2 = [];
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++, j++)
    {
      if (!/^\s*$/.test(str.charAt(i)))
        {
          str2[j] =  str.slice(0, i) + str.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + str.slice(i + 1)
        }
      else if (i + 1 < str.length)
        {
          i += 1;
          str2[j] =  str.slice(0, i) + str.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + str.slice(i + 1)
        }
    }
  console.log(str2)
  console.log(str.length)
  return str2;
  
}
```

when i run it on test mode it gives me

[image: this is the image]

when i run it on attempt mode it gives me

[image: this is the image]

It's  fine with the basic test but it doesn't work with the random test this is the error and I don't know how to fix it, it looks like it's an error with the if statement not triggering correctly

[image]

Comment: Your loop and the `else` block progress `i` by 2 when you have a whitespace character (making you skip the next character). Is there any reason why you're trying to handle whitespaces differently to other characters? Calling `.toUpperCase()` on them will leave it as a whitespace character

Comment: What is the problem statement?

Comment: There's no point in using anchors and `*` in the regexp. `charAt()` always returns a single character.

Comment: BTW, you can just write `str[i]`, there's no need to call the `charAt()` method.

Comment: yes @NickParsons because i am supposed to skip white spaces because no letter gets capitslized btw why i skip an i is because if i dont skip it when the array is returned their will be an empty variable so i will go like ['I am', 'empty space' , 'i Am', 'i aM']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is when there are two spaces in a row. Your problem is that in your `else` block, you're assuming that if you encounter a space, then the next character won't be a space, and pushing that into `str2` (resulting in the word containing no uppercase letters, as you just pushed a new item by trying to capitalize a space).

Instead, remove the `else` block entirely. It's not needed as you'll handle the next non-space character once you eventually reach it in your loop, don't try and handle the next character in advance, as your loop will do that for you when you get to it. Note that you now only need to increase `j` when you add a transformed word to your array, not on every iteration

```js
function wave(str) {
  var str2 = [];
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (!/^\s*$/.test(str.charAt(i))) {
      str2[j] = str.slice(0, i) + str.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + str.slice(i + 1);
      j++;
    }
  }
  return str2;
}

console.log(wave("hello"));
console.log(wave("abc  efg"));
```

The above code can be simplified to remove the regex check and the `j` counter by using `.push()`:

```js
function wave(str) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != " ") { // or just str[i] != " "
      result.push(str.slice(0, i) + str.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + str.slice(i + 1));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(wave("abc  efg"));
```

Comment: thanks man i new it had to do with the else and then i++